# 'The Walking Dead' on iOS vs Console Editions

Tags: version-differences, the-walking-dead-season-one

What are the differences between iOS and PS3 versions of The Walking Dead? How do they compare, especially graphically?

Is the iOS version missing anything from the big screen version? I would think that touch screen would be good for a game like this, but don't want to get a stripped down build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story and everything is the same but the controls change depending on the console or pc or iPhone (Anything you play it on)

Comment: I bought and finished the iOS version. It looks like apart from the control scheme they are the same. Fun fact - lots of people complained about the console and PC versions (freezes, crashes, missing saves). I was playing on iPhone 5 (yes, on a phone) and it was very smooth with no glitches at all.